# Automatic Mysql backup to mdb (Microsoft Access)

Tags: php, mysql, bash, ms-access

I am a Spanish Telecommunications student and I am doing external practice with a medical company.

I'm working on a company intranet software which is a web application where the doctors and secretaries can add new patients and their medical diagnosis.

The problem is that the Spanish regulation of health obligate to have backups of the database and these backup copies can be readable without Internet access.
The company prefer to have a Microsoft Access copies because it's regular in little medical clinics.

I know that with the odbc driver I can read data from MySQL database and write to Ms Access, but I need automatic backup in Microsoft Access.

If it is not possible, can it be possible with any other database system?

Thank you very much in advance !!

Comment: I would caution that medical records are *so sensitive* and the regulations concerning them are *so strict* that this is probably not a task that should be undertaken by a lone, inexperienced student.  If nothing else, who will support this system once you have moved on?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please read the answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269359) to understand why this type of question (in its current form) is not well-received on Stack Overflow.